# Logstash - input file plugin to keep data in memory

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, join, apache-kafka, logstash

I have 1- a single CSV file and 2- a live KAFKA stream. KAFKA stream brings in live streaming logs and the CSV file contains metadata records that I need to join them with the streaming logs before sending them to Elastic Search.

Example of a Kafka stream log and a CSV record:

```
KAFKA log: MachineID: 2424, MachineType: 1, MessageType: 9
CSV record: MachineID: 2424, MachineOwner: JohnDuo
```

Record I need to build in logstash before sending to ES:

```
MachineID: 2424
MachineOwner: JohnDuo
MachineType: 1
MessageType: 9
```

I want a solution either a Ruby or Logstash plugin or anything else to read this CSV file once
and bring them in and join them in the Logstash conf file. I need to keep the content
of the CSV file in memory otherwise CSV look ups on each live Kafka log kills my Logstash performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`translate`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-translate.html) filter.

You would need something like this.

```
filter {
    translate {
        dictionary_path => "/path/to/your/csv/file.csv"
        field => "[MachineId]"
        destination => "[MachineOwner]"
        fallback => "not found"
    }
}
```

Then you in your `file.csv` you will have the following.

```
2424,JohnDuo
2425,AnotherUser
```

For every event that has the field `MachineId`, this filter will look up for this id in the dictionary, if it finds a match, it will create a field named `MachineOwner` with the value of the match, if it does not find a match, it will create the field `MachineOwner` with the value `not found`, if you do not want to create the field in the case of a no match, you can remove the `fallback` option.

The dictionary is loaded in memory when logstash starts and it is reloaded every 300 seconds, you also can change that behaviour.

Comment: Can I create multiple destination field in one filter if my CSV files have multiple fields Ex MachineID, MachineOwner, Address, Phone, etc